# I am getting error "rord() is not supported over Points based field" in SOLR 7.5. How to fix it?

Tags: solr

For boosting purpose in SOLR 7, I am using function

```
recip(rord({dateField}),1,1000,1000)
```

But getting the error in SOLR that

> rord() is not supported over Points based field

How to overcome this issue in SOLR 7. However it is working fine in SOLR 6.5 as in schema.xml dateField is instance of TriDateClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ms` to get the millisecond value for the date field instead of it's reverse ordering position in the index. It works with both point based and Trie based fields.

> ms Function
>
> Returns milliseconds of difference between its arguments. Dates are relative to the Unix or POSIX time epoch, midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

For example `recip(ms(NOW, last_modified), 3.16e-11, 1, 1)`. You can also change `NOW` to be a static date that changes each day to get better cachability for your query.-

Comment: I was wondering, how did you come up with the value for m=3.16e-11?

Comment: It's the default one used in the examples for Solr, and changes the units from ms to a year - i.e. a document one year old corresponds to a boost of 0.5: "A multiplier of 3.16e-11 changes the units from milliseconds to years (since there are about 3.16e10 milliseconds per year). Thus, a very recent date will yield a value close to 1/(0+1) or 1, a date a year in the past will get a multiplier of about 1/(1+1) or 1/2, and date two years old will yield 1/(2+1) or 1/3."